# How to mount snap rings/circlips?

Tags: tools

This is a question about finding a tool - I hope I'm in the right place? I have an old Singer Sewing machine, which had one of these springy steel rings around the base of the lamp, and I had to open it up and solder the wire inside. It was easy enough to get off, but how do I put it back?

The ring looks like the picture below - I have been looking for some kind of pliers, but they all seem to be meant for the kind of clip the has little eyelets. Is it possible to put back without special tools?

[image: Circlip or snap ring]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually sit the ring on the end of the tube or shaft and hold it there with my thumb, then use a small screwdriver to push it on completely, takes practise and luck.

Another method is to have a tube of a slightly larger diameter so it will slide over the other tube and use that to push the ring on squarely - then a vice can help.

Comment: Hey, it actually worked, with the screwdriver, after a few mishaps! Thanks a lot!